# Update Solr elevate.xml on remote solr server

Tags: solr, solr4, solrnet

I am using Solr 6 for Dot Net MVC Application. And working on implementing elevation feature. Note that the Solr is hosted on a remote server. And we can not directly access the Solr server so we can't write directly to elevate.xml file.

i) are you using solrcloud? Why can't you access the remote server (permissions, firewall, etc...)? Yes. Its a third party service that does not allow this.

Why do you need to modify the elevate.xml file instead of using alternative solution?

We need to modify elevate.xml file to update it. The alternate method of sending elevated Ids during query is a different technique, we choose to update elevate file instead due to kind of use case.

In this cases, how do we write / update elevate.xml file hosted on remote solr server. Is there any API to update the elevate.xml file on remote server. What is the best possible solution for that.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Please edit your question adding the following info: i) are you using solrcloud? Why can't you access the remote server (permissions, firewall, etc...)? Why do you need to modify the elevate.xml file instead of using alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solrclient uses Zookeeper as centralised and sync repository for all its configuration files.  The answer to your question and the best practice,  is to use zkCli.sh on ssh as explained [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Command+Line+Utilities) in order to update any configuration file like elevation.xml,  solrconfig.xml, etc.... For instance you can use a cmd like:

```
./server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost 127.0.0.1:9983 \  -cmd put /my_zk_file.txt 'some data'
```

The script can be ran from any machine having the client installed.